# XPS 8920 Crashes after Windows 10 update - Page fault in nonpaged area

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, updates, dell-xps

This happens after a quality update as well as a feature update to 21H2, the system won't boot and blue screens with the error (where the fault happened isn't shown on the blue screen). These are the system specs:

```
[System Summary]

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model XPS 8920
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU 07DC
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 3600 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date Dell Inc. 1.0.23, 6/11/2020
SMBIOS Version 2.8
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer Dell Inc.
BaseBoard Product 0VHXCD
BaseBoard Version A00
Platform Role Desktop
Secure Boot State Off
PCR7 Configuration Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory C:\WINDOWS
System Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "10.0.19041.1503"
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
Total Physical Memory 31.9 GB
Available Physical Memory 27.0 GB
Total Virtual Memory 32.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory 27.6 GB
Page File Space 1.00 GB
Page File C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection Off
Virtualization-based security Not enabled
Device Encryption Support Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7
binding is not supported, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

These are all of the drivers installed on the system:

```
devicename                                                                                driverversion
----------                                                                                -------------
                                                                                          2:10.0,2:6.3,2:6.2,2:6.1,2...
                                                                                          2:10.0,2:6.3,2:6.2,2:6.1,2...

                                                                                          2:10.0,2:6.3,2:6.2,2:6.1,2...
                                                                                          2:10.0,2:6.3,2:6.2,2:6.1,2...
                                                                                          2:10.0,2:6.3,2:6.2,2:6.1,2...
ACPI Fan                                                                                  10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Fan                                                                                  10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Fan                                                                                  10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Fan                                                                                  10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Fan                                                                                  10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Fixed Feature Button                                                                 10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Power Button                                                                         10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Processor Aggregator                                                                 10.0.19041.1
ACPI Sleep Button                                                                         10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Thermal Zone                                                                         10.0.19041.1202
ACPI Thermal Zone                                                                         10.0.19041.1202
ACPI x64-based PC                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Audio Endpoint                                                                            10.0.19041.1
Bluetooth Device                                                                          10.0.19041.1387
Bluetooth Device                                                                          10.0.19041.1387
Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)                                                  10.0.19041.1
Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)                                                    10.0.19041.1
Bluetooth Peripheral Device
Bluetooth Peripheral Device
Card  Reader                                                                              10.0.19041.746
CD-ROM Drive                                                                              10.0.19041.1266
Communications Port                                                                       10.0.19041.1
Composite Bus Enumerator                                                                  10.0.19041.1
DBUtilDrv2 Device                                                                         2.7.0.0
Dell Data Vault Control Device                                                            2.0.6.0
Dell Data Vault Control Device                                                            2.0.6.0
Dell IN1910N(Analog)                                                                      3.0.0.0
Disk drive                                                                                10.0.19041.789
Disk drive                                                                                10.0.19041.789
Generic IEEE 1667 ACT                                                                     10.0.19041.1
Generic IEEE 1667 Probe Silo                                                              10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic software device                                                                   10.0.19041.1
Generic volume shadow copy                                                                10.0.19041.1
Generic volume shadow copy                                                                10.0.19041.1
Generic volume shadow copy                                                                10.0.19041.1
Hauppauge HD-PVR2 Gaming Plus (Model 157xxx)                                              1.6.37119.0
Headset Audio Gateway Service                                                             10.0.19041.1387
HID Keyboard Device                                                                       10.0.19041.1
HID-compliant mouse                                                                       10.0.19041.1
High Definition Audio Controller                                                          10.0.19041.1081
High Definition Audio Controller                                                          10.0.19041.1081
High precision event timer                                                                10.0.19041.1202
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel Processor                                                                           10.0.19041.546
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (Z270) - A2C5                           10.1.1.38
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 - A291                        10.1.1.38
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 - A292                        10.1.1.38
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 - A293                        10.1.1.38
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family PMC - A2A1                                             10.1.1.38
Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family SMBUS - A2A3                                           10.1.1.38
Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller                                         17.5.3.1026
Intel(R) Display Audio                                                                    10.27.0.9
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165                                                       19.51.30.1
Intel(R) Dynamic Application Loader Host Interface                                        1.41.2021.121
Intel(R) Graphics Command Center                                                          27.20.100.8681
Intel(R) Graphics Control Panel                                                           27.20.100.8681
Intel(R) HD Graphics 630                                                                  27.20.100.8681
Intel(R) iCLS Client                                                                      1.63.1155.1
Intel(R) Management and Security Application Local Management                             2130.1.16.1
Intel(R) Management Engine Interface                                                      1952.14.0.1470
Intel(R) Pinning Shell Extensions                                                         16.8.3.1003
Intel(R) Power Engine Plug-in                                                             10.0.19041.1266
Intel(R) Ready Mode Technology Device                                                     1.2.0.0
Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller - INT3451                                         30.100.1816.3
Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - A2E0                                             30.100.1943.2
Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - A2E1                                             30.100.1943.2
Intel(R) Serial IO UART Host Controller - A2A7                                            30.100.1943.2
Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)                                                            20.100.7.1
Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200 v6/7th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Host Bridge/DRAM Registers - 591F 10.1.1.38
Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901 10.1.1.38
Legacy device                                                                             10.0.19041.1202
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Local Print Queue                                                                         10.0.19041.1
Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System                                                           10.0.19041.964
Microsoft Basic Display Driver                                                            10.0.19041.868
Microsoft Basic Render Driver                                                             10.0.19041.868
Microsoft Bluetooth A2dp Sink                                                             10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth A2dp Source                                                           10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver                                                10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver                                                10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver                                                10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Avrcp Transport Driver                                                10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator                                                            10.0.19041.1387
Microsoft Bluetooth Hands-Free Audio device                                               10.0.19041.1266
Microsoft Bluetooth Hands-Free Audio device                                               10.0.19041.1266
Microsoft Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile AudioGateway role                                  10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile Handsfree role                                     10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator                                                         10.0.19041.488
Microsoft Hyper-V Virtualization Infrastructure Driver                                    10.0.19041.1466
Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter                                                    10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller                                                       10.0.19041.1503
Microsoft System Management BIOS Driver                                                   10.0.19041.1
Microsoft TCG Storage silo                                                                10.0.19041.1
Microsoft UEFI-Compliant System                                                           10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Virtual Drive Enumerator                                                        10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter                                                    10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter                                                    10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI                                           10.0.19041.1
Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI                                           10.0.19041.1
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
Motherboard resources                                                                     10.0.19041.1202
NDIS Virtual Network Adapter Enumerator                                                   10.0.19041.1
Numeric data processor                                                                    10.0.19041.1202
NVIDIA GeForce GT 730                                                                     23.21.13.9125
NVIDIA High Definition Audio                                                              1.3.36.6
NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)                                       4.4.0.0
NVVHCI Enumerator                                                                         2.2.2151.6378
Object Push Service                                                                       10.0.19041.1387
PCI Express Root Complex                                                                  10.0.19041.1387
Personal Area Network NAP Service                                                         10.0.19041.1387
Personal Area Network Service                                                             10.0.19041.1387
Phonebook Access Pse Service                                                              10.0.19041.1387
Plug and Play Software Device Enumerator                                                  10.0.19041.1
Programmable interrupt controller                                                         10.0.19041.1202
Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)                2.1.0.26
Realtek Audio                                                                             6.0.1.8248
Remote Desktop Device Redirector Bus                                                      10.0.19041.1
SdlProxy
SMS/MMS
Standard Serial over Bluetooth link                                                       10.0.19041.1
Standard Serial over Bluetooth link                                                       10.0.19041.1
System CMOS/real time clock                                                               10.0.19041.1202
System Firmware                                                                           10.0.19041.1
System timer                                                                              10.0.19041.1202
UMBus Root Bus Enumerator                                                                 10.0.19041.1
USB Input Device                                                                          10.0.19041.868
USB Input Device                                                                          10.0.19041.868
USB Mass Storage Device                                                                   10.0.19041.1288
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)                                                                    10.0.19041.1202
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)                                                                    10.0.19041.1202
USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller                                                        10.0.19041.1503
USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller                                                        10.0.19041.1503
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume                                                                                    10.0.19041.1
Volume Manager                                                                            10.0.19041.928
WAN Miniport (IKEv2)                                                                      10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (IP)                                                                         10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (IPv6)                                                                       10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (L2TP)                                                                       10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)                                                            10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (PPPOE)                                                                      10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (PPTP)                                                                       10.0.19041.1
WAN Miniport (SSTP)                                                                       10.0.19041.1
XSplit  Stream  Audio  Renderer                                                           2.0.1406.2601
```

I'm able to recover from the bsod with Startup Repair or System Restore. And yes, I know this machine isn't compatible w/ Windows 11. The problem is, since Windows update can't be disabled anymore, only "delayed" for up to 35 days, this happens every 35 days.

I would like to know if anyone can point out a known incompatible driver that I've missed updating or some verbose logging I can enable that will point out what the issue is.

Comment: It's simple enough to indefinitely postpone updates. It's just a horrible idea.  You basically just recent your activity hours every 12 hours.  Why do you bring up Windows 11 when you don't even have it installed?  Since you are running Windows 10 21H2 you don't have to worry about any more feature updates being released.  You would have to provide more information than just a list of devices for us to diagnose the driver issue. For instance the output of a WinDBG analysis.

Comment: I'm not running 21H2 @Ramhound. It crashes everytime I attempt to install it, so the updates get rolled back. I brought up 11 to attempt to ward off suggestions to upgrade the machine to 11.

Comment: So you have been unable to install the enablement package for 21H2 since you are running 21H1?

Comment: @Ramhound That's right, nor have I been able to install quality updates for 21H1. I will try WinDBG next time I am onsite.